# EF not using SQL index when filtering with StartsWith

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

The following LINQ query filters rows with a `StartsWith()` predicate:

```
db.Pictures.Where(pic => pic.Filename.StartsWith(path)).Count();
```

Which translates into the following SQL (from SQL Server Profiler):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Pictures] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Filename] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N''~''
)  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'10429\2\6\%'
```

The `Filename` column is of type VARCHAR(255) and is indexed.
However, the query does not use the index because of the N in `ESCAPE N'~'`.

In the query execution plan I can see a warning:

> Type conversion in expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(NVARCHAR(255), [Extent1].[Filename], 0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice

The query runs fine (uses the index) when the N is removed.

How can I fix this issue?

(One obvious solution might be to change the type of the column to NVARCHAR, but that doesn't seem ideal since I do not actually need to store unicode data)

Comment: Did you try mapping `Filename` explicitly as VARCHAR?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set your model to also be varchar.  You can configure that by overriding `OnModelCreating` in your Context.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Picture>().Property(p => p.Filename).IsUnicode(false);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to specify I was using code-first but you guessed right!